# how to display data from now until one week ago in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to display the data from `now` until `one week ago`.

i have query uses the where statement as

```
WHERE date 
BETWEEN 
(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
AND 
CURRENT_DATE();
```

It shows data for past 1 week but does not include today. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Show me your difinition of `date`, please. Is it a `datetime` type?

Comment: date is name field

Comment: Post your DDL..

Comment: sorry i don't know what is DLL?

Comment: It's *DDL* (Data Definition Language), not *DLL* (Dynamic Link Library) :-). DDL describes the layout of your tables, views, etc., i.e. this "CREATE TABLE table1 (id int)" would be the "description" for a new table with the name `table1` with one colum `id` of type integer. @walter would like to see the definition of your table to check the column type of your `date` column.

Answer (score 0):

`current_date` will wait till midnight i.e. till the day/date is over. Use `now()` to display data till the current timestamp.

Make sure the datatypes (date/datetime/timestamp) are consistent. Cast them where ever required.

**Important:** Avoid using operators with the datatype they are not meant for. I see, you're using `-` (minus) with date/timestamp. A better way would be : `subdate(now(), interval 1 week)`

Comment: @andruwoei: replace `(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND CURRENT_DATE();` with `subdate(now(), interval 1 week)`

Comment: it show error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`. i dont have syntax limit in my qurey??

Comment: If it's related to MariaDB, why the question is tagged with `MySQL`? This format is for MySQL and works correctly there. Cannot assure about MariaDB.